# Mysql composite index, best practice

Tags: mysql, indexing

We have a database structure where all tables have the cols `company` and `shop`, where the relation is one-company-to-many-shops. So an order table would have the cols `id`, `company_id`, `shop_id`, `col_a`, `col_b`, `col_c`... etc. All queries to suchs table would have a where statement beginning with `company_id = xx AND shop_id = yy...` followed by the actual search on specific columns.

So the question is how to construct the index for e.g `col_a` and `col_c` when I know that `company_id` and `shop_id` always are included in a where statement. Should i create composite indexes for each like (`company_id`, `shop_id`, `col_a`) and (`company_id`, `shop_id`, `col_c`). Or should the strategy be a composite on (`company_id`, `shop_id`) and singles on (`col_a`) and (`col_c`).

Mysql version 5.7

Thanks in advance

Comment: If a shop can only be in a single company you can probably remove these company_id columns

Comment: One table copy may use only one index, so *composite on (company_id, shop_id) and singles on (col_a) and (col_c)* makes no sense. I recommend you to define the most used col_N columns (2-3, not more) and create one composite index which includes these columns. From the other side, if `(company_id, shop_id)` is highly selective then you don't need in additional columns in the index at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a composite index, list all columns tested with `=` first.  The order of those in the `INDEX(...)` does *not* matter.

Then list one 'range' if necessary, or `GROUP BY` in order, or `ORDER BY` in order.  The details get messy; see
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Those guidelines may lead to some or all of these:

```
(cid, sid, a, c)
(cid, sid, c, a)
```

Note that the first of those works well even if `c` is not mentioned anywhere in the `SELECT`, but the second one would be *less* good.

But it is useless to have

```
(a) and (c)
```

Unless you need something like

```
SELECT shop_id FROM t WHERE a = 123
```

In that case, you need a single-column or composite index *starting* with `a`.

(As Guillaume points out, `company_id` should probably not exist in more than a single table, namely `Shops`.)